# How to remove duplicate from list<Map<String,Object>>

Tags: java, collections

How to remove duplicates from a List of Map? Below is the code snippet.
In a Map multiple duplicate entries will be there for one value. I want to remove those duplicate values.

```
        List<Map<String, Object>> obtainAuditLog = pddBamControlDao.populateAuditLogMap();
```

Comment: I think you should provide more details, maybe some example of what you think duplicate is.

Comment: The same way you remove duplicates from any list: either copy it to a set, and then back into the list; or using streams to do the same; or check each element to see if there is a preceding element in the list to which it is equal.

Comment: What would constitute a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

You can use java stream API to remove duplicates from the list:

Sample code:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> obtainAuditLogNoDuplicate = obtainAuditLog.stream()
                                                      .distinct()
                                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```